# Firebase - Should Anonymous UID get deleted after Existing user is Logged In?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have `Anonymous` enabled as one of my `Sign-in providers` so that a user can browse my app without actually needing to login.

Once an anonymous user is created, they get a random `uid`

[image]

If that user never created an account, when they do sign up via email or phone, they get a new uid.

But if the user had previously signed up, then signs out, when they open the app they'll have random uid. When they sign in with their actual email or phone, they'll end up using their actual uid, at which point the random uid will be useless. Should I delete that random uid from the database or keep it there? I haven't found anything that suggests what to do with anonymous uids that are no longer in use.

For example:

```
let anonymousUserUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid // "abc..."
let anonymousUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID, verificationCode: verificationCode)
    
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (authDataResult, error) in

   guard let userId = authDataResult?.user.uid else { return }

   let usersRef = Database.database().reference()
        .child("users")
        .child(userId)
   usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self](snapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists() {
           // turns out this anonymous user is already registered and their uid is "xyz..."

           // is it a good practice to now delete the anonymousUser?
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the documentation on [Firebase Authentication limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#accounts_per_project), each project can have up to 100 million anonymous accounts.

Leaving the UIDs for abandoned anonymous user accounts in the system is mostly harmless. But if you get millions of them or they get in the way for another reason, you can delete them.

Comment: quick question, using the code above, in the usersRef completionHandler, would this delete the currentUser after they are authenticated or would it delete the anonymousUser: `anonymousUser?.delete { (error) in { ... }`. I get the impression that after the user is signed in the `Auth.auth().currentUser` would switch to the signed in user and all I would be doing is deleting them.

Comment: If you want to delete any existing anonymous user, you should do this before calling `signIn(with...)`. If you want a seamless upgrade, consider linking their new credentials to their existing anonymous account instead of signing them in with those credentials as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking